# Problems with simple code generating rnd number which is divided by 5

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write simple code that will generate a random number from 10-99. And this number is supposed to be divided by 5. It works up until line 13.

```
using System;

namespace C_Test2
{
    class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rnd.Next(10, 99));
                int h = 0;
                int del = 5;
                float h = j / del;
                Console.WriteLine("Vores tal divideret med 5 er lig med: " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm having difficulty with the division part. I can't get past boolean and int problem.

EDIT: Thanks everybody, I'm a beginner and the code posted was all I could perform with my current understanding and knowledge of coding. As said before edited gone, I'm new!

Comment: Firstly, you're doing nothing with the random number.  You're just writing out to the console.   You're also  declaring `h` twice.  That's not gunna work.  That's as far as I've looked.

Comment: If possible try to paste the output as well. It'll increase clarity of the code.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4oMVqz  I just renamed the second h variable and it seems to work. The random value is currently unused though.

Comment: What is the question here? Any error?

Comment: I have no output, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: int h not important to my code, dont mind that

Comment: @TimSchmelter it does compile though, just doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @TimSchmelter at least with johey's changes to the code

Comment: I guess I'm fishing for someone to help me with how to divide int j with 5(int del)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hade some error:

- variable h is declared two times
- rnd.Next(10,99) never used
  As I understand your problem this must be solution, just change the body of main method

  ```
   Random rnd = new Random();
       for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
       {
           int randNr = rnd.Next(10, 99);
           Console.WriteLine(randNr);                
           float del = 5;
           float result = randNr / del;
           Console.WriteLine("Vores tal divideret med 5 er lig med: " + result);
       }
  ```

Comment: worth noting that `del` must be declared as float to avoid integer division which truncates the decimal part.

Comment: Thanks, It's working! @Drl thanks for the contribution to my beginner mistakes

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring h twice. First it was of `integer` type and then of `float` type. This is going to cause compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because the `h` variable is declared twice.

Furthermore, the number generated with `rnd.Next(10, 99)` is not stored anywhere, so if you want to divide it by 5, you'd have to do something like this:

```
using System;

namespace C_Test2
{
    class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                int random = rnd.Next(10, 99);
                Console.WriteLine(random);

                float del = 5;
                float h = random / del;
                Console.WriteLine("Result of division: " + h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `del` has to either be declared as a float or converted to a float so that the result has decimal places.